# Solving $a_n=1+\sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k}$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> We define a sequence by $a_0=0$ and $$a_n=1+\sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k}\quad n\ge1$$
>   Find a non-recursive formula for $a_n$.

Not homework, this is a question from my friend. I tried to use summation by parts
$$
\sum_{k=m}^na_kb_k
=A_nb_n-A_{m-1}b_m-\sum_{k=m}^{n-1}A_k(b_{k+1}-b_k)
$$
But it doesn't make this problem easier. I am wondering if this problem is a special one ($a_0=0$) and then it has a non-recursive formula. Any hints would be highly appreciated!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes, it's $n$.

Comment: It doesn't make much difference, since the terms involving $a_n$ are $a_0a_n$ and $a_na_0$, which both are $0$. If you know about generating functions, they will be very useful for this problem

Comment: @Wojowu Could you please explain more about it? I know a little about generating functions but I didn't figure out how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sketch of a solution using generating functions. Let $F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$. We then have
$$F(x)^2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_ka_{n-k}\right)x^n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_n-1)x^n=F(x)-\frac{x}{1-x}.$$
Using the quadratic formula you can now solve for $F(x)$. To get the formula for the coefficients, you may want to use the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series).

Answer (score 3):

Note we can drop the $k=n$ term because then $a_{n-k}=0$. Your sequence is the [binomial transform of the Catalan numbers](https://oeis.org/A007317). It can be described with many formulae, including yours, credited to Cloitre 2004. The closed form is $F(\tfrac12,\,-n;\,2;\;-4)$ in terms of the ordinary [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Comment: Impressive, we have posted out answers on exactly the same second!